# how can we use flexbox and responsive units like % for several images?

Tags: css, flexbox, responsive-design

I want to put three images next together by using flexbox and responsive units in this case percentage(%). I have 2 issues: (1) justify-content does not work because I use % for flex items. (2) The tall of my images are getting bigger than the wide, in other word width and height of my images are not relative together because I used auto keyword for the height of images so I can have width and height relative. I would be very grateful if you could help me. I will include my code below.

```css
.services h2 {
  margin: 3.125rem 0 2rem;
}

#services-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.service-item {
  width: 90%;
  height: 65%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.service-item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section class="services">
  <h2>our services</h2>
  <div id="services-container">
    <div class="service-item hotel">
      <img src="./resources/pictures/hotel.jpg" alt="hotel">
      <h4>The best hotels</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="service-item air-plane">
      <img src="./resources/pictures/airplane.jpg" alt="airplane">
      <h4>The best airline services</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="service-item food">
      <img src="./resources/pictures/food.jpg" alt="food">
      <h4>The highest quality foods</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[image]

Comment: @Johan   thank you but it did not help they took the height if the page.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can set the `height` to 100% and `width` to auto and use `justify-content` on parent like so :

```
.services h2 {
margin: 3.125rem 0 2rem;
}

#services-container {
display: flex;
width: 100%;
justify-content: space-between;
}

.service-item {
width: 30%;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}

.service-item img {
width: auto;
height: 100%;
display: block;
}
```

Hope it helps